# phpbrew install specific php version (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I am using phpbrew have installed specific php version use:

```
phpbrew install 5.3.10 +default +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

show me a information:

```
Apache module dir /usr/lib/apache2/modules is not writable.
Please consider using chmod or sudo.
```

i have no idea how to do that.if someone can help me, it will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the user you're running as does not have permissions to modify the directory `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`, which is necessary to do the installation. You're advised to either modify the permissions of the directory using `chmod` (bad idea unless you know what you're doing) or to run the command with superuser credentials via `sudo`:

```
$ sudo phpbrew install 5.3.10 +default +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```

Comment: What are the implications of running this command with `sudo`? Will PHP still be installed in my home directory? Will I have to use `sudo phpbrew` to switch to this php? Can I safely `chown` all PHP files to my user after the installation? I've had some terrible experiences with `sudo npm`, so I always prefer to not use sudo when possible. But maybe `phpbrew` is smarter than `npm` when it comes to permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run same command using sudo

```
sudo phpbrew install 5.3.10 +default +apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
```